# Como transformar um array de bytes em uma imagem no WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um array de bytes como esse:
`private byte[] m_Frame`

Preciso transformar ele em uma imagem, só que como estou em um `WPF` não é possível simplesmente jogar um `bitmap` dentro de um `PictureBox` porque esse elemento simplesmente não existe no `WPF`.

Por enquanto, tenho esse desenvolvimento:

```
BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
bmpi.BeginInit();
bmpi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(m_Frame);
bmpi.EndInit();
m_picture.Source = bmpi;
```

Obs: `m_picture` é um `<Image/>`

Mas quando vou chamar o método que esse trecho está inserido o `VS` me retorna um `Exception:System.NotSupportedException: 'No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.`

O que preciso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Minha solução

Para resolver o problema precisei de fato criar, de alguma maneira, um `PictureBox` do `WF` dentro do meu projeto de `WPF`.

Para fazer isso, primeiro adicionei referências aos assemblies a seguir.

> - WindowsFormsIntegration
> - System.Windows.Forms

E dentro da lógica do meu programa:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
```

*Este cria a interação necessária para criar elementos `WF`*

```
PictureBox m_picture = new PictureBox();
host.Child = m_picture;
this.myStackPanel.Children.Add(host);
```

*Crio aqui meu PictureBox e depois jogo pra dentro do `host`, e o mesmo, para dentro de um `StackPanel`do meu projeto `WPF`*

Mas para de fato chegar em uma imagem partindo do meu `[]byte m_Frame` criei um `Bitmap` com alguns recursos de uma `API` e joguei dentro do `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa um MemoryStream:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = null;

using (MemoryStream ImageDataStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageDataStream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
    ImageDataStream.Position = 0;
    bData = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, bData);
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageDataStream);
}
return img;
```

onde `bData` é o array de bytes

Comment: Ao executar a linha img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageDataStream) esse erro está retornando: System.ArgumentException Parameter is not valid. Sabe o que pode ser?